# Compress directory for backup

Tags: 20.04

Id like to compress var/www/all sites for backup. What would the command line be to compress them and all sub folders. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `tar` and a few convenient options:

```
tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz /var/www
```

The `-zcvf` option list breaks down like this:

- `-z`: Gzip the archive
- `-c`: create archive
- `-v`: verbose mode (show you what’s happening)
- `-f`: set the file name

If you choose to automate this, you can include the current date in the file name like this:

```
tar -zcvf backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz /var/www
```

Comment: Thank You , much appreciated

Comment: where would this save to, i expected it to be var ?

Comment: If you are running this manually, it will be saved to the current directory. If you want it saved to a specific location, you can specify it with a full file location after the `-zcvf` bit 

Comment: good man, thanks